# is it necessary to call pthread_exit()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I create 2 threads without any  `pthread_exit()` and I add 2 `pthread_join()`
Is there any problem? Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: there was no problemes !! that's why I asked !! where are we obliged to add 'pthread_exit()' ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not required to call `pthread_exit`. The thread function can simply return when it's finished.

From the man page:

> An implicit call to pthread_exit() is made when a thread other than
>   the thread in which main() was first invoked returns from the start
>   routine that was used to create it. The function's return value serves
>   as the thread's exit status.